# creating a shape over a Range object in Winword Addin

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am trying to create a shape over a given Range object in winword addin.

Currently I am only able to get the left and top of the begining of the Range , but I can't find the witdh and height of that range.

This is what I am doing to get the top/left :

```
                float left= r.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);
            float top= r.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage);
```

to add the shape I am doing something like that over the Selection object which hold the range :

```
Sel.Document.Shapes.AddShape((int)Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 
                left, 
                top,
                100, 
                100, r )
```

In addition to that, I would like to be notifed whenever that range is changing (changing its content).

Comment: For detecting content change there is a selection change event. If selection changes then you can do a diff of before and after to detect what has changed. I dont know another way

Comment: Selection change event will trigger when I add/remove elements from a paragrah ? doesn't it triggers when you select difference elements ?

Comment: If the selection in the document changes, the event will fire. Maybe this won't help you however

Comment: Since width and height doesn't seem to be available natively by Interop for the Range, maybe we're looking at this the wrong way. Can you expand on the problem? If there is no native way for us to get the width and height, maybe we can come up with our own way.

Comment: I am simply trying to highlight a section of text with a shape. if the text was changed, I wish the highlight section will expand and cover the new text (as long as it in the selection section border)

Comment: Might be a way to construct your own "width" and "height" of a Range by converting the Characters within the Range to point values and calculating the distance between top and bottom characters to get the height, and first and last characters on a line to get the width. Not sure, just thinking outloud here..

Comment: You should ask a separate question about the "would like to be notifed whenever that range is changing (changing its content)". That is another animal itself. (But I am certain it is possible)